# Do I have a superpower?

Tags: discussion, privileges, comment-flags, deleted-comments

A high-rep answerer posted two comments in the question asking the OP to accept the answer.

I thought two comments were too much noise and asking for acceptance is not good etiquette.

So I flagged one of these comments as "not constructive".

Immediately, the comment disappeared. I reloaded the page to confirm, and the comment was not there. It's marked as helpful in my list of flags.

Do I have the mod superpower to delete comments, or what did just happen?

Just to test, I flagged the other comment as "too chatty" but it has not been deleted (pending flag).

Comment: AFAIK some comments get auto deleted if you flag them and they meat a certain criteria. Also if enough people flag a certain comment they can also get auto deleted. So sorry no super power for you.

Comment: OK, thanks. I searched but I could only find posts about rejected flags.

Comment: It’s a quiet simple logic. If a certain number of flags is required for deleting a comment, one user will be the last one, whose flag makes the number complete, hence, (s)he is the one to perceive an immediate effect, while all others witnessed a delay. This repeats on every flagged comment (unless you’re flagging for moderator’s attention explicitly).