# Is there a penalty for asking too many questions without accepting answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I recently came across this question: [how to display an image in react from postgresdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140223/how-to-display-an-image-in-react-from-postgresdb).

A user with a high amount of reputation (13k+) left a comment saying:

> A warning: you have asked too many questions without accepting
>   answers. Your account may be closed or penalized if you continue to
>   ask questions without accepting answers. Please click the empty
>   checkmark next to correct answers to help others find them

Is that really true - can an account be closed or penalized if one is not accepting answers? Are there any penalties?

The help center states that

> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept
>   the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that
>   answers your question well.

So I'm guessing there aren't penalties, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm glad this question wasn't what I thought it was going to be based on the title.

Comment: @Janar Flag that comment for moderators to step in and tell that user to stop posting such comments.

Comment: Grrr. People making up rules and confusing newbies with them piss me off - especially when, as is usually the case and indeed is the case here, those "rules" are harmful and we [actively don't want the newbies to follow them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273100/1709587). I hope the mods give the user in question a suitably stern spanking for this behaviour.

Comment: Is the user who posted that comment the same user as the user who posted the answer?

Comment: you should just drop a flag at this comment and see how it disappears immediately. After that you'd probably ask here: [Do I have a superpower?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340904/839601) :)

Comment: There is no such a rule, as you know by now. But it's a good idea explaining the OP that accepting an useful answer is a polite thing to do, and a small token for receiving a - free! - help. When I see a user with 10 or 20 questions, all of them without accepted answers, I just drop a comment explaining that. However, when I see a user that clearly knows how to accept (they have 1 or 2 accepted ones) but, despite that, has dozens of questions without accepted answers I simply walk away...

Comment: Not all questions have answers worth accepting. I know I have a few questions that have answers but I haven't accepted any answer to them because either I didn't get the chance to check the answer (in one case) or the answers given did not solve the problem. However, If I see a comment by the OP like "Thanks, that worked fine" and no accepted answer, I usually comment to the OP something like "Please accept this answer so that other people will know that the problems is solved". This is the main reason IMHO to accept answers in the first place - to save other people time and effort.

Comment: Btw, thanks. You've inspired me to answer some of my unanswered questions myself.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I usually say something a little more general, like "_If my answer or any other answer helped you, you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer_", that way I'm not asking/telling the OP to accept _my_ answer, but any of them that helped them.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm not asking to accept only my answers. In fact, I have left several comments like that on other people's answers where the OP commented that they fixed the problem. It's not about asking to accept *my* answer, but to accept the *correct* answer. (sometimes, there is more than one. In that case, I would argue to either accept the answer given by the lower rep user since they need the 15 rep points more, or accept the earliest correct answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I wasn't assuming bad intentions on your part, I was just adding to the conversation :) I agree with leaning toward accepting answers given by lower rep users if they are similar in quality to a higher rep user.

Comment: @Mark Amery: I have considered posting a PSA here about "backseat modding", which is a bannable offense in most traditional forums (for obvious reasons).

Comment: @BoltClock frame that as a *discussion* and I'd be very interested to read it. The trouble is that the boundary between what is and isn't acceptable is fuzzy. By giving us proles the power to comment, downvote, and close vote, the system innately gives us some right to engage in moderation. It doesn't seem wrong to point out rule violations (e.g. I frequently comment pointing out that lack of disclosure of affiliation with a recommended tool or failure to properly indicate what content in a post is copied violate our guidelines). The problem comes when the rule being asserted is *wrong*.

Comment: When I post answers to new users (who might not be aware of the whole accept/up-vote thing) I leave them a comment, something like: *"If any of the answers solved your issue, please consider marking them as accepted. This helps future readers know that said post answered your question."*. I try making it clear that it isn't mandatory, but appreciated, and that the asker should accept the best answer (if there are more than 1) and not necessarily *my* answer. I've found this approach to be quite helpful.

Comment: FWIW, 13k rep isn't that much nowadays.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Relatively relative, only about 0,0015% of all the users have more than 10k rep.

Comment: If you ask a lot of questions and don't accept or up-vote many answers, you may find people less willing to help you.  If you get help from the answers, you should say thank you - and that's done by up-voting useful answers and accepting the most useful.  And marking the answer accepted gets you a small bonus (2 points), and indicates to the world that this question has reached a satisfactory conclusion for the person answering it.  But, good manners apart, there's no formal penalty for not accepting answers.

Comment: My standard spiel is: _Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[What do I do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Comment: @Mark Amery: Reminding another user of the rules - and citing your sources - is just about as far as I'd go in moderating other users as a regular user. Anything beyond that really should be left up to the diamond mods. Regular users shouldn't be acting, or speaking on behalf of, the diamond mods or the staff (this is what backseat modding means). Even we are told not to threaten any sort of punitive action in our mod messages - regular users have even less of a right to do that.

Comment: @Mark Amery: Up, down and close votes are used for moderating content - we are even repeatedly told to vote on the content and not the person. The only abilities given to regular users to "moderate" other users are comments and flags - the site expects you to defer user behavior problems and other non-content-related rule violations to us using flags, and comments should be advisory at best, not written in such a way as to assume any position of authority.

Comment: @BoltClock Asserting non-existent rules can still be a problem even if you're strictly targeting content instead of users, though. Plenty of *questions* get criticised for bullshit reasons - the most common of which goes along the lines of *"Hi! I see that you asked a question without 100 lines of broken code in it. That's not allowed here. Stack Overflow is a service for debugging your code. You can't just ask us how to do something; instead, write some code that doesn't work, then ask us to fix it for you."*

Comment: I've seen members who have a lot more questions without a single accepted ones. Pointing them to the help page doesn't help

Answer (score 121, accepted):

No, there is no penalty whatsoever for not accepting an answer — [*it is entirely optional*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Accept rate was at one point publicly visible, but [this hasn't been the case for years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/336144), because it ended up being used simply to harass askers who didn't have a 'satisfactory' accept rate.

**There is no automated system to penalise askers who don't accept answers.** You won't lose rep; you won't be banned from the site or have your account closed. If you ask many *poor* questions, which are badly received by the community, you might receive a question ban, but accepting an answer probably doesn't affect the question ban algorithm (it's impossible to know for certain, as the details are kept secret). The only thing you miss out on is the +2 rep bonus for accepting an answer.

[Discussing accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23321/336144) generally isn't an appropriate use of comments, which are there to help clarify or improve questions. While commenting once [if the user ***genuinely doesn't know*** about the feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251288/6650102) is tolerated, these comments are generally just noise and aren't necessary.

Comment: "Accepting an answer is entirely optional" is often answered to similar questions, because theoretically there is no real difference between a question with an accepted answer vs. without. I could live with that, but why then is Community bumping 'unanswered' questions to the home page?

Comment: @usr2564301 "Unanswered" on Stack Exchange means that the question has no accepted **or** upvoted answer. A question is counted as answered as soon as it has one upvoted answer, and so accepting an answer isn't necessary for the question to be resolved. Community only bumps questions with answers but not "answered" (i.e. only questions with no upvoted answers) to get attention so that old answers can be vetted by the community and the best can rise to the top. That is the idea of Community's bumping: to get other users to step in and review the answers when no-one's done that yet.